# How to get only files only from specific path folder (or path prefix) in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I want to get only files only from a specific path folder (or path prefix) in an S3 bucket. But the below code is recursively searching for files at the path and giving files from subfolders also.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='xx',
    aws_secret_access_key='xx'
)

my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('test')
for s3_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='\test\folder_with_files'):
    path, filename = os.path.split(s3_object.key)
    keyslist.append(s3_object.key)
    bucket, key = s3_object.key.split('/',2)[-1].split('/',1)
#I am trying to get the last slice from the output path prefix as filename above
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s3sr = resource('s3')
bucket = 'your-bucket'
prefix = 'your-prefix/' # if no prefix, pass ''

def get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    '''gets list of keys and dates for given bucket and prefix'''
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    # use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
        keys_list.extend(keys)
    return keys_list

keys_list = get_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix)
```